# Find heading for a device

Tags: android, android-sensors, magnetometer

I need to find the heading(in terms of degrees east or west of north) for an Android device that is being held vertically(like this: [Heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wqHa.jpg)) . I accessed the sensor.event[2] values returned from the geomagnetic sensor and found that they vary from 1 to 35 as I rotate the device completely about vertical axis. How can I convert this value to a heading? A very brief explanation or a link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at SensorManager.getOrientation  It returns 3 angles, around the 3 axes.

```
Computes the device's orientation based on the rotation matrix.

When it returns, the array values is filled with the result:

    values[0]: azimuth, rotation around the Z axis.
    values[1]: pitch, rotation around the X axis.
    values[2]: roll, rotation around the Y axis.

The reference coordinate-system used is different from the world coordinate-system defined for the rotation matrix:

    X is defined as the vector product Y.Z (It is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and roughly points West).
    Y is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and points towards the magnetic North Pole.
    Z points towards the center of the Earth and is perpendicular to the ground.
```

You'll need to use the geomagnetic and accelerometer sensors to feed in the data to get the rotation matrix.  Look at SensorManager for more info